# How to make embedded YouTube video work in IFrame in Cordova app in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, angular7, youtube-iframe-api

I have converted my Angular 7 app to IOS app using Cordova(PhoneGap). In that app, I am trying to play youtube video using `IFrame`, but unfortunately, the video is not playing. An only the video preview is shown after whitelisting the domain.

It always says "video unavailable".

FYI: The app also signed using IOS-Distribution certificate.

**Added Code:**

```
<platform name="ios">
<allow-navigation href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/*"/>
</platform>
```

**Expected:**

Video should play

**Actual Result:**

An only video preview is shown. The video is not playing.

Comment: 'Video unavailable' means youtube either can't or wont send the video to the player, so first things first have you tried another video? and secondly is the youtube client installed on the device if so does the video work in the client?, it could also be that 3rd party cookies (iframes or XSS) are blocked on iOS so it might be the player can't set the cookies it needs. go into settings and enable 3rd party cookies in safari

Comment: I have tried of course another video. Yes, the video is working in youtube native app, but not in my PhoneGap app. Actually its an app, so do I still need cookies for that? Apart from that, I had this similar issue in the web app, but after turning my web app into https, it has worked. @MartinBarker

Comment: Yeah, all PhoneGap or Codova are, are a Browser with Javascript methods added to it it still operates as a browser have you all so checked or set up your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ... />`?

Comment: I did that @MartinBarker But still not working. It turns out to be youtube is not allowing the video to play in mobile, which I don't get it.

Comment: I believe it's because they want videos to play in there app on devices. what you might be able to do is set up a hyperlink around an image with target="__new" and the device should identify to use the correct app.

Comment: Yeah, but it does not make sense for my app to redirect to another app since my its a music app. Do you any other alternative to play that video? For example, it works on my website. @MartinBarker

Comment: Well if it's your music app stop using youtube altogether, and that is probably why Google have this restriction on youtube so your app not stealing their Bandwidth, Server resources for your self.

Comment: This is not possible, because I am running via Iframe that means it is working exactly like in the browser.  Because some apps doing that. I guess it works if I run it via native apps. @MartinBarker My app working in the browser for example https://musicwithcappacino.com